# Cannot access server outside of localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, server

I have a node.js server running on Ubuntu 19.10 and runs perfectly on **localhost:port** but when I try to access it via **ipadress:port** a slow loading appears on my phone and computer until connection timeout. I've also encountered err_connection_refused
[image]
I turned off the firewall and the problem still persists. I tried port 88443,3000,443. My server is running on http2 but I tried with a simple http server on port 80 and the problem persists.

I programmed the server to log every time a request is recieved and none have been recieved when using the ip.

Is it a problem with the security of Ubuntu? Or is it Node.JS? What do I have to disable to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a public or private IP address to try to get to your server?

Comment: Tried with local ip using node.js os network interfaces and with the local IP i get from my module https://www.npmjs.com/package/dondetoy . I'm connected via WI-FI router

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly need to forward the ports on your router.